# Form validation in Flask

Tags: python, flask

This is my flask form for login form. It does not like this validation that requires both university form field as well as email form field - the error that I keep on getting is

**TypeError: validate_university() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'**

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
     username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
     password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
     password2 = PasswordField(('Repeat Password'), validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])
     university = SelectField("What University do you go to?",choices=[("soton","University of Southampton"),("solent","Solent
 Southampton University")])
     email=StringField("What is your university email?",validators=[DataRequired(),Email()])
     submitpassword = SubmitField('Submit your password choice')

     def validate_username(self, username):
         user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
         if user is not None:
             raise ValidationError(('Please use a different username.'))

     def validate_university(self,university,email):
         uni = University.query.filter_by(code=university.data).first()
         if not email.data.endswith(uni.emailend):
             raise ValidationError(("Please enter correct university e-mail for the university you attend."))

         user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
         if user is not None:
             raise ValidationError(('This e-mail is already in use. Please use a different email address.'))
```

This is the corresponding route python function :

```
 @bp.route('/reg1', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
 def reg1():
     if current_user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect(url_for('main.index'))    
     form = RegistrationForm()
     if form.validate_on_submit():
         user = User(email=form.email.data,username=form.username.data)
         user.set_password(form.password.data)
         db.session.add(user)
         db.session.commit()
         flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
         return redirect(url_for('auth.reg1'))
     return render_template('auth/test.html', title='Register',
                            form=form,lenform=lenform,postcodes=postcodes)
```

How can i fix it? Why does it not allow me two positional arguments for university validation form? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuastom validation methods have to be defined with the "form, field" signature, meaning you can not have a validator with the (self,university,email) parameters.

You can, however, access other fields of the form in your validator through the form parameter:

```
 def validate_university(form, university):  # <- correct signature
     uni = University.query.filter_by(code=university.data).first()
     email = form.email  # <- access the email field like so
     ....
```

Comment: This has worked. Thank you! I would upvote your comment, but I dont have enough reputation to do so, yet!